# Why PgUp key error massage in my Autohotkey text?

Tags: autohotkey

[Hope that if ` typed, shift+tab key twice, Page-up key twice are typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFiy.png)

[but with error massage, it does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h0Hc.png)

```
`:: send +{tab}

+{tab}

{pgup 2}
```

Hope that if ` typed, shift+tab key twice, Page-up key twice are typed.
However with error massage, it does not work.
What is the problem? How can I fix it? I am not a expert or developer but will do what I'm told. Please help!!

Comment: `send +{tab 2}{pgup 2}` To get familiar with AutoHotkey read the [**Beginner Tutorial**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm)